# Get SlidingDrawer reference inside it's open/close events

Tags: android, android-listview, slidingdrawer

I'm using `ListView` with `SlidingDrawer` inside its list items.

I want to add the `SlidingDrawer` open/close events that will get a reference of the -drawer that was opened/close as I want to get it's tag.

Is there a way I can access the `SlidingDrawer` object through the open/close events?

Answer (score 0):

What I did eventually was creating new Listeners implementing `OnDrawerOpenListener` and `OnDrawerCloseListener`, adding the `SlidingDrawer` reference to their constructors and storing it as a member accessible in the `onDrawerOpened`  and `onDrawerClosed` methods.